# "Какая модель это?" or "Какой модель это"?

Tags: перевод

What is the correct form?

> "**Какая** модель это?"

or

> "**Какой** модель это?"

I'm quite sure that the correct form is "Какой модель это?" but google translate - translate "which model is it" into "**Какая** модель это?" and I'm afraid maybe I'm not right.

[image]

Comment: while the "is" verb is omitted in Russian, the place it could take somewhat gaps, so it naturally gets filled with some other word - or small pause. Here "это" put in the position of the missing verb would make the phrase sound smooth and natural.

Comment: While only "какая модель это" is correct, you might hear something like "какой модели (gen.) это" which has generally the same meaning.

Answer (score 6):

модель is a feminine noun (IIIrd declension, f words ending with -ь) so the right adjective would be какая as it goes with модель.

Comment: I always thought that the word model is masculine noun. My mistake.

Comment: That's right, even male models are feminine in Russian: Он рабо́тает моде́лью (He works as a model).

Answer (score 3):

Словоформы слова "модель"

модель  →   модель – существительное, **жен. р.**, именительный. п., ед. ч.
└   модель – существительное, жен. р., винительный п., ед. ч.

Часть речи: существительное

Единственное число  Множественное число

Им. модель  модели

Рд. модели  моделей

Дт. модели  моделям

Вн. модель  модели

Тв. моделью моделями

Пр. модели. моделях

You can find this information on the site morfologija.ru Грамматический словарь русского языка online. The word is feminine, so какая модель is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can be sure only about grammatical gender of abstract nouns derived from adjectives and ending in ***-сть***; they are 99,999% feminine.

The grammatical genders of other words ending in the soft sign are better to be learned by heart.

The correct form is therefore ***какая + модель***.